# Slow wifi speed Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB RAM

Tags: wifi

I just cannot figure out why my Pi has such lower wifi download speed - around 65 - 75 Mbps, measured with speedtest-cli. It is connected to a 5GHz SSID. It is a new Pi model 4B 8GB RAM with an original power supply. It has Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed just a day ago and it does not run any applications. I get from my ISP 700 Mbps when connected with Ethernet cable, and between 400 - 600 Mbps from all other wireless network devices but not from the Pi. I searched for a solution and to identify the issue but I can't find it.
What should I do? Thank you very much for your help and advise.

Comment: the pi has this tiny little pcb antenna that is good, if you're next to the access point - what's the wifi signal strength on th epi

Comment: What WiFi speed did you expect, and why?

Comment: In the room where I keep the Pi (20 ft away from the AP)– signal level=-69dBm, download: 75.20Mbps, upload: 61.50Mbps
Next to the AP (1 ft away) – signal level=-10dBm, download: 81.79Mbps, upload: 71.13Mbps

Comment: I am expecting a speed in the same range as the other wireless devices on the same 802.11ac network - around 400-600Mbps. Even half of that would be much better performance than the current one.

Answer (score 1):

"I am expecting a speed in the same range as the other wireless devices on the same 802.11ac network - around 400-600Mbps"

This is impossible! 802.11ac might be able to reach these speeds on a good day with the wind behind it **but only on suitable hardware** - that means multiple antenna MIMO.

The tiny **single** antenna on the Pi4 will never get close; the best you could expect is 150Mbps on a 5GHz network. [MagPi benchmarks](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks) show  114 Mbps.

NOTE `speedtest-cli` is not a reliable method of testing WiFi - it is an end to end test of internet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
“NOTE speedtest-cli is not a reliable method of testing WiFi - it is an end to end test of internet.” 
I just did tests with iperf3 between the Pi, foot away from the AP, and a laptop connected with CAT6 cable. Both on 802.11ac network. Upload-82Mbps, Download-87Mbps. If there is another tool to measure properly the speed, please, let me know.

Comment: “..the best you could expect is 150Mbps on a 5GHz network. MagPi benchmarks show 114 Mbps” – it looks like with the tools I used to access the speed, the speed is far from these numbers, and that is if the Pi sits next to the AP. I was just wondering if there is some kind of config that I am missing and maybe that is why the performance isn’t better. Thank you again for your time.